# Debug Draw mask All is not working in cocos2d-JS of BOX2D,

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-js

I have tried all of below mentioned code but none of this is working

```
    this._debugNode = new cc.PhysicsDebugNode(this.physicsWorld);
    this._debugNode.visible = true;
    this.addChild(this._debugNode, 10)
```

Getting crash when using this one:

```
    var debugNode = new cc.PhysicsDebugNode(this.physicsWorld);
    debugNode.visible = true;
    this.addChild(debugNode);
```

I have also tried this one, but it's also not giving any output.

```
    var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
    debugDraw.SetSprite(cc.renderContext);
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(32);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.8);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit);
    this.physicsWorld.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd solve the above mentioned question by pasting this code in to update method.

   ```
       var debugDraw = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw();
       debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("debugCanvas").getContext("2d"));
       cc.log( "this.m_ctx "+  document.getElementById("debugCanvas").getContext("2d"));
       debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30.0);
       debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(1.3);
       debugDraw.SetLineThickness(0.5);
       debugDraw.SetFlags(Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
       this.physicsWorld.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
       this.physicsWorld.DrawDebugData();
   ```

   2. Paste This code  into index.html

      ```
        <canvas id="debugCanvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border:5px solid #FF0000;"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       var debugCanvas = document.getElementById("debugCanvas");
       debugCanvas.width = 1200;
       debugCanvas.height = 600;
       debugCanvas.style.left = "50px";
       debugCanvas.style.top = "0px";
       debugCanvas.style.position = "absolute";
      </script>
      ```